# Remove additional elements depending on screen size in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a slideshow/carousel but I want to show an even number of images depending on the screen size.

So if the screen can fit 5 images the slider will show 5 etc,. The issue is if the screen only fits 4 I want to remove the 13th,14th and 15th image so that it will have 4 images on screen at a time and won't show three with a gap at the end.

In this example:

```
var slides_div = document.getElementById("container");
for (var k=11; k<slides.length; k++) {
    slides_div.removeChild(slides_div.childNodes[k]);
}
```

this bit is not removing any elements but on my computer it is removing images 5 and 6. On my version it is all one page with inline js/css and nothing else in the file.

```js
var doc_width = $(document).outerWidth(true);
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");

if(doc_width > 1310){
 no_slides = 5;
}else if(doc_width > 1060){
 no_slides = 4;
 
 var slides_div = document.getElementById("container");
 for (var k=11; k<slides.length; k++) {
  slides_div.removeChild(slides_div.childNodes[k]);
 }
 
}else if(doc_width > 810){
 no_slides = 3;
}else if(doc_width > 560){
 no_slides = 2;     
}else if(doc_width > 310){
 no_slides = 1;
}

var first_slide = 0;
var last_slide = no_slides-1;
showDivs(first_slide,last_slide);

function prev_slides() {
 showDivs(first_slide -= no_slides, last_slide -= no_slides);
}
function next_slides() {
 showDivs(first_slide += no_slides, last_slide += no_slides);
}

function showDivs(f,l) {
 if (l > slides.length) {
  first_slide = 0;
  last_slide = no_slides-1;
 }
 if (l < 1) {
  first_slide = slides.length-no_slides;
  last_slide = slides.length-1;
 }
 for (var i=0; i<slides.length; i++) {
  $(slides[i]).css({"opacity": 0, "right":"+=250", "display":"none"});
 }
 for (var j=first_slide; j<=last_slide; j++){
  $(slides[j]).css({"opacity": 1, "right":"0", "display":"inline"});
 }
}
```

```css
.container{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
}
.arrow{
 vertical-align:middle;
 width:30px;
}
.slides{
 position:relative;
 width:250px;
 opacity:0;
 right:-200px;
 display:none;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
 <img class="arrow" src="arrow_left.jpg" onclick="prev_slides()">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/111111?text=1">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/222222?text=2">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/333333?text=3">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/444444?text=4">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/555555?text=5">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/666666?text=6">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/777777?text=7">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/888888?text=8">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/999999?text=9">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/aaaaaa?text=10">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/bbbbbb?text=11">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/cccccc?text=12">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/dddddd?text=13">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/eeeeee?text=14">
  <img class="slides" src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100/ffffff?text=15">
 <img class="arrow" src="arrow_right.jpg" onclick="next_slides()">
</div>
```

Comment: you could do this with `css` by using `@media`

Comment: @Matt.S I don't think that would work because I want to remove them rather than just hide them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was picking up null objects between the images for some reason.

Then in the loop things would be indexed differently after each item was removed so had to loop backwards.

Changed it to the following and it works the way I want:

```
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("trustpilot_slides");
for (var k=slides.length-1; k>=14; k--) {
    var this_slide = slides[k];
    this_slide.parentNode.removeChild(this_slide);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use CSS media queries to hide the last 3 HTML elements.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .hideme {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div class="hideme">5</div>
<div class="hideme">6</div>
<div class="hideme">7</div>
```